# Generating clumps of pixels in an image in Python

Tags: image, python-3.x

I'm attempting to write a script that generates a binary image of randomized pixels that preferentially groups pixels of similar values together (i.e. the "clumping" from the title), similar to the first attached image. My code nominally approaches this, in that I have multiple sets of conditions where the probability of a white pixel is higher when another white pixel resides in its immediate neighborhood (same for black), but it outputs images like the second attached image. Are there any libraries or methods I can exploit to generate images like the first one?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import timeit
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, JoinableQueue
import math
from PIL import Image

arr_size = 200
arr = np.zeros((200,200))

X = 200
Y = 200

num_sections = 10

def phase_neighborhoods(section_number):
    #section size definitions go here

    neighborhood = lambda m, n: [(m2,n2) for m2 in range(m-1,m+2) for n2 in range(n-1,n+2) if (-1 < m <= X and -1 < n <= section_size and (m != m2 or n != n2) and (0 <= m2 <= X) and (0 <= n2 <= section_size))]
    #this function defines the immediate neighborhood for each pixel

        for y in range(section_size):
            for x in range(arr_size):

                rnd_e1 = random.random()
                rnd_e2 = random.random()
                counter_e1 = np.zeros(num_sections)
                counter_e2 = np.zeros(num_sections)

                if rnd_e1 <= 0.11892865364043818:
                    arr_section[y,x] = 255

                for i in range(len(neighborhood(y,x))):
                    if arr_section[neighborhood(y,x)[i][0]-1, neighborhood(y,x)[i][1]-1] == 255:
                        counter_e1[section_number] += 0.15

                if rnd_e1 <= 0.11892865364043818+(counter_e1[section_number]*0.2):
                    arr_section[y,x] = 255

                for i in range(len(neighborhood(y,x))):
                    if arr_section[neighborhood(y,x)[i][0]-1, neighborhood(y,x)[i][1]-1] == 0:
                        counter_e2[section_number] += 0.25
                if rnd_e1 >= 1-0.11892865364043818-(counter_e2[section_number]*0.02):
                        arr_section[y,x] = 0

#if __name__ == '__main__' etc etc
```

I've cut out extraneous parts of the code since much of it is parallelization code (thus the `section_size` and `section_number` variables)

[image: This kind of clumping is the goal].
[image: This is the code's result]

Comment: What’s the point of this - I am intrigued :-)

Comment: Element composition structures! This is a rudimentary chemical data supplement to a 3D texture synthesis code, where I take given volume fractions of elements and how they clump with themselves and each other and use those probabilities and trends as inputs into a microstructure in order to recreate a statistically similar elemental composition map. If that makes sense. I've already generalized the above code to 3D and multiprocessing, but I can't get clumps and voids to emerge properly